# A Cargo Ship Big as a Star Destroyer

Tags: construction, materials, ships, steampunk, shipbuilding

In the world of steampunk, regular means of transportation are bigger in size than in real life.

This scenario regards cargo transportation.  The largest so far is China's CSCL Globe, no longer than 400 meters.

[image]

In this steampunk scenario, the CSCL Globe is four times longer, the length of an Imperial II-class star destroyer that debuted in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

So a steampunk seagoing cargo ship measures 1600 meters in length, but its proportions between length, tonnage, beam (width at the widest point) and draft (vertical distance between the waterline and the bottom of the hull, with the thickness of the hull included) remain the same.  Would this kind of size be feasible, or would the materials and manpower required be a *Star Wars*-level degree of handwavium?

Comment: The limitation on the largest ships is draft, not engineering knowledge. There is no reason you couldn't make a ship 1600m long. However, scaling CSCL Globe's draft up by a factor of four to 64 m means it couldn't even approach most ports (rare is the ship channel dredged beyond 30m).  If you made Globe 1600m long and correspondingly wide, but only 16m deep, you would have tremendous stability problems with cross-beam waves. Probably not enough to sink the ship, but enough motion to ruin the cargo.

Comment: And you would also need a reason to haul so much cargo. 4 times longer means 4*4*4=64 times more cargo. This means 64 * longer wait before shipping makes sense, 64 * longer stay in port, and so on. Would it make sense for your people?

Comment: @kingledion Can't help but feel that both of these comments would be good as answers.

Comment: @Molot: See above

Comment: @JoeBloggs OP asks about materials and manpower. My comment is not even near touching these aspects. That's why I made it a comment. John, what do you think? Would you consider these to be answers? Your question, your call.

Comment: @Molot Fair point.

Comment: @Mołot  I say kingledion's comment is the only valid one.

Comment: Given the [number of ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_container_ships) with a length of almost exactly 400m, I suspect there's some practical consideration (either draft, as @kingledion says, or the size of some straight/canal/port they all want to be capable of using;  [not the panama canal, which appears to be 320m, possibly the straight of malacca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_Canal#/media/File:Panama_canal_lock_sizes.png)).

Comment: Also, [BBC article discussing container ship size](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-21432226)

Comment: @Kevin The biggest ships can't use ANY canals. The limit is called [Chinamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinamax). It is designed around the port infrastructure of China, mostly the 24m draft limit, since that is how deep the channels are dredged.

Comment: The largest ship is actually 458 meters. and it is significantly heavier than the globe.  http://maritime-connector.com/worlds-largest-ships/ The real issue with length is storms, super large ships do not handle storms well.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with ship size (in terms of length and width) is fairly easy to overcome if one feels so inclined: you need a port where this ship can land. Arguably it would be possible to load and unload a ship at sea, but since this is not the biggest concern, we can as well skip it. 
It might still play a role in your story, though.

Then of course there is the question what your ship is supposed to do. 
A very large ship is economical to have and operate only if you make use of most of it. So for a cargo ship, there must be a constant demand for sufficiently large volumes of cargo to be shipped from exactly one point to exactly one other point, lest more smaller ships be more efficient.

What is actually limiting the size (particularly the length) of any seafaring vessel is the strength of it's hull.

While lying in calm waterns, you could have almost any size of ship. But waters are not always calm. 
Travelling through waves you have varying support of your ship's hull by the water. The crest of a wave provides more lift than the trough by the simple fact that a rigid ship lies deeper in the crest. The lift is provided by the water displaced.

So, if you hit a big enough wave that lifts half your ship, while the other half hangs in mid-air, the hull will break.

You could theoretically create a hull that has some latticework-like interior frame that helps distributing the forces involved, but there are economical limits to that. Eventually, adding more length will result in most of the ship being the structure to handle it's own weight (which is weight, too, which in turn requires the same weight in water to be displaced...) and hardly any useful space for whatever payload you have in mind will remain.

Also, all this weight has to be accelerated.

So, the practical size limit for your ship is determined by:
 - the ports you try to reach
 - the materials you have at your disposal for creating the structure
- the reason you built your ship in the first place, i.e. the space requirements

Answer (score 1):

Using a 'mobile' structure of this size purely for cargo transport would be under using it enormously. A ship of this size could be a portable ore refinery, factory and a load of other things. This kind of ship could sail near the landmasses that produce raw materials for collection and then sail to the market and create the goods on the way. This ship could even be considered portable infrastructure depending on its load-out.

A standard hull probably wouldn't work as the wave distribution would be too uneven. A multi hull design may be more stable. EG: 
[image]

Even if the ship is steady, its not going to dock-able in any harbor. It will be the mother ship for its own fleet for loading and unloading. Think less ship and more moving island.

Comment: Stress on a catamaran hull would be unbelievable. There is a reason giant bulk carriers and tankers are all single hull; it is much stronger and more stable.

Comment: I love the idea of the factory/city ship that loads up with raw materials at one port, manufactures all the way to it's destination, and unloads the finished product at the end.

Comment: @kingledion , yes this may not be an ideal hull type and the size of this vessel will require some novel designs. As Burki points out, a standard hull scaled up won't work.